# ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
    ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
```

That's my problem and code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER czwarty 
    INSTEAD OF INSERT 
    ON zlozona FOR EACH ROW
    AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO klienci(id, imie, nazwisko)
    VALUES (4, imie, :NEW.nazwisko);
    END;
```

What's wrong? I did almost everything :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should not be an `AS` before the `BEGIN`.  If you need to declare local variables in your actual code, you would need to use a `DECLARE` not an `AS`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON view_name
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  local_variable_declarations_here
BEGIN
  code_here;
END;
```